# PCI Tv Tuner not receiving signal

Tags: tv, pci, coaxial

I inherited an Angel II PCI Dual TV Tuner card, popped it into my computer's PCI slot, plugged in my coax cable, but am having trouble getting any type of signal to it. The computer I am using is Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit, I know the card works because the computer recognizes it and installs the drivers, or at least I assume it works because of that. I'm trying to use Windows Media Center to watch/record tv. Here are a few things I have tried to get it working:

- Uninstalled/Reinstalled the newest drivers
- Tried hooking up an antenna to the coax input instead of my cable
- Instead of using cable splitter, went directly from wall output into card with coax cable
- Tried using different output on splitter in case the out port was bad

I haven't tried a different coax cable yet, it should be fine since it's pretty new. Since this is my first time setting up a TV Tuner card, is there anything specific that I need to do with it? Is there any configuration that needs to be done on it? Do I need to have a digial receiver? I was getting pretty frustrated with it so I wanted to turn here to the experts, I'm sure someone can help me figure it out.

Comment: I know that some TV tuners require some sort of software component to do some of the higher level functions like channel changing, and such.  Is there specific software that goes with the card?

Comment: @hydroparadise I didn't receive any software with it and the manufacture website doesn't list anything either except some freeware you can use, which I tried and didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.dtv.gov/topfaqs.html#faq1) may have some relevance to your problem.  TV tuners were more popular *before* the whole digital conversion in TV.  You might want to check if your card is digital ready.